# mysql erro na criação de foreign key

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando criar uma foreign key, porem ela da erro.
Segue o código que estou usando:

```
 CREATE TABLE foto(
    id INT(10),
    img varchar(25),
    nome varchar(25),
    link varchar(25),
    vew INT(10),
    tkm VARCHAR(100),
    moder INT(1),
    CONSTRAINT fot_id_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
 CREATE TABLE inter(
        id INT(10),
        img varchar(25),
        nome varchar(25),
        link varchar(25),
        vew INT(10),
        tkm VARCHAR(100),
        moder INT(5),
        CONSTRAINT int_id_pk
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        CONSTRAINT int_moder_fk
        FOREIGN key (moder)
        REFERENCES foto (moder)
    );
```

erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que as colunas são incompatíveis.

Coluna na tabela foto:  `moder INT(1)`
Coluna na tabela inter: `moder INT(5)`